# How to create a diagonal matrix with a shorter list of diagonals in Python?

Tags: python, dimension, diagonal

Suppose I have a list of diagonal entries, `d`, is there a simple way to create a diagonal matrix like `A`? Can I specify the dimension of the result using `np.diag(d)`?

```
import numpy as np

d = np.array([1,2])

A = np.array([[1,0,0,0], [0,2,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```py
A = np.zeros((4,4))
A[:2, :2] = np.diag(d)
```

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. Thank you!